# 3 Different Types of "click" effects for Jquery. Differences and issues with each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, event-bubbling

Recently I have been making a web app. I noticed there are 3 different types of "click" effects for Jquery.

**1:**

```
$("element").click(function() {
```

This one works on all devices, but has issues with dynamically generated elements. This I know. The real issue comes with the later.
**2:**

```
$("element").on('click', function() {
```

**VS**
**3:**

```
$(document/element).on('click', "element", function() {
```

I was using the third option because it works for all elements, both predefined and generated. It works great on windows->chrome. I went to test my web app on Iphone->Safari, and not a single click effect would work. I finally realized that it was the type of click. It seems option **3** does not work on Iphone, but option **1** and **2** do. Can someone explain this? Does option **2** work for dynamically generated elements? I want to be sure I dont have click issues when I deploy. Thanks!

Comment: No, that's incorrect; it probably has to do with how iOS Safari translates "touch" events into "click" events or how your specific code is set up. The third approach (event delegation) does work generally.

Comment: so weird.... If i change it from $(document/).on('click', "element", function() { **TO** $('body').on('click', "element", function() { **DOESNT WORK** but if I change it to $('#parent-element').on('click', "element", function() { it does... but former example works on desktop lol? wtf?

Comment: Usually I use `$("body")` but I've also used `$(document)` and never had a problem.